# Translations won't be loaded into template files when using dragend JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-translate

**Issue**

Translations won't be loaded into template files when using [dragend JS](https://github.com/Stereobit/dragend). I have debugged a lot and concluded that it has to do with the dragend JS declaration. The translations appears when i comment away the `dragend()`, bot won't appear when I uncomment it and reload the page.

The template files are appearing with it's HTML correctly. And dragend JS is doing it's job with fixing the slides. It's just that they don't get the translations into it.

The translations for header and footer works though.

**The Code**

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ["ngRoute", 'pascalprecht.translate']);

myApp.config(["$routeProvider", '$translateProvider', function($routeProvider, $translateProvider)
{
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "home.html"
        ,controller:"StageController"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "about.html"
        ,controller:"StageController"
    });

    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'lang/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sv');

}]);

myApp.controller('StageController', ['$scope', '$translate', function($scope, $translate) 
{
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey)
  {
    $translate.use(langKey);
  };

  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function()
  {
    // Translations for templates won't load when using this:
    $(".ui-content").find(".dragend-pages").dragend();
  });

}]);
```

**Environment**

- angular-translate - v2.9.0 - 2016-01-24
- AngularJS v1.6.1 Google
- Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)

**Demo**

https://plnkr.co/edit/5G3jJxF3DSfClzfopGEg?p=preview